# How can I perform interpolation between two numbers arranged in tabular format in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I've some values of x and corresponding values for y arranged in a tabular format.
For example:

```
x: 0.0,  0.1, 0.2,   0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6
y: 2.43, 2.26, 2.13, 1.96, 1.82, 1.64, 1.49
```

So if my value for `x is 0.234`; in that case, the MATLAB program should be able to interpolate the corresponding value of y (between 2.13 and 1.96).

Comment: So what have you tried? Have you read the docs for `interp1`? This is very straightforwad in Matlab

Answer (score 1):

You can use interp1

```
x = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6];
y = [2.43, 2.26, 2.13, 1.96, 1.82, 1.64, 1.49];
interp1(x, y, 0.234)
```

The value is 2.0722

[image]